# Facebook always shows scrollbars around Flash applications

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml

For some reason, scrollbars are always showing around my flash player on my app. Please see one of my pages below which has my app which displays a flash player and i've tried all I can to remove the scrollbars around it;

http://www.facebook.com/trubeats?sk=app_79482449955

I've tried it in Mac and Windows - Safari, IE, Firefox and Chrome but no they all show the scrollbars. You can see the image below if the scrollbars don't show up for you in your browser. I just don't understand, a few people online have had the same problem, but their solutions don't work for me. Anyone have any idea?

[image]

UPDATE

Canvas image

[image]

Comment: It would mean that the app is too big but it happens in the canvas too (see updated screenshot) - i've never had a problem with it in the past, it's only started happening recently, and no dimensions have been changed, it's the iframe around the Flash app that FB have added that is adding the scrollbars and there doesn't seem to be a way to control it.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time I'm able to kill scrollbars by adding this to the body tag:

```
<body onload="FB.Canvas.setSize();">
```

And I usually take it one step further and do this, so that when links are clicked within the iFrame, the scroll is reset to top:

```
<body onload="FB.Canvas.setSize(); FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);">
```

Just a quick 2¢, no guarantees. Good luck.

Comment: will also help to make sure the main content is no larger than 520px, perhaps set explicitly in css.

Comment: Thanks for the help but this doesn't work as fb doesn't allow the body tag - this is the error I get `FBML Error (line 71): illegal tag "body" under "fb:canvas"`

Comment: oh... i thought fbml apps were deprecated. i've only been doing iframe apps. ah well. best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your css like this

```
html,body {
  width:520px;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border:0;
}
```

and use 
FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();

Comment: Where do I put the FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();?

Answer (score 0):

Page Tab Canvas width is 520 pixels wide, and your flash is wrapped in `div` with width 525 pixels. This results in horizontal scroll displayed.

Same `div` have also height of 398 pixels but embedded flash displayed in `iframe` with 402 pixel height for content. Which is resulting in vertical scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it doesn't just happen in my tab, it happens in the canvas where there is sufficient space (please see above for updated post with screenshot of my canvas). What FB have started doing it wrapping the Flash app within an iFrame, and this iFrame is the thing that's causing the problem, because you can't control it! It's the iFrame that's adding the scrollbars but there doesn't seem to be a way to control the overflow CSS of it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Kevin, you're a genius! This worked perfectly for me. Maybe it's best to set the height to "1" and then use the FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow() to auto increase the height to fit the content.